# Ubuntu 11.10 Sound Stopped Working (Speakers and Headphones)

Tags: 11.10, sound

Ubuntu 11.10

My speakers have stopped working - no sound is coming out.
The headphone port is also not working.

When I plug in headphones now, no "jack plugged in" alert is popping up anymore.
I can adjust and mute the sound via buttons and sound settings, but it doesn't affect the playback.

A few weeks ago, this happened a few times, and I was able to fix the sound by muting/unmuting the sound a few times and increasing/decreasing the volume, but now it will not work.

---

Steps I have taken:

- Installed the latest ALSA drivers according to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS
- `sudo modprobe snd_hda_intel`
- Purged and reinstalled alsa-base and pulseaudio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update ubuntu using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

worked for me after restarting.

Note: My keyboard shortcuts were reset as a result, and my touchpad didn't work for one boot cycle, but it all works perfectly for me now. I hope this command can help someone else!