# Sound input and output suddenly stopped working on a Dell Inspiron 13 with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, sound, updates, pulseaudio, alsa

Until May 3rd everything was working fine, I was being able to listen to Youtube videos and do Hangouts meetings and on the 4rth I was going to do a Hangouts meeting and suddenly I couldn't listen to anyone & no one could listen to me.

What I have done so far:

1. I've ran Dell System Tests - so it's not a hardware issue. My laptop is emitting and getting sounds.
2. I've uninstalled, reinstalled, fixed and altered pavucontrol, alsamixer and pulseaudio. Everything is unmuted and configured correctly and registering sound from Youtube videos. To be more specific the sound bars move, but I can't hear anything.
3. I've connected my laptop to a tv and the sound output is working fine with the HDMI cable.
4. I've tried using headphones to see I the sound works and they don't work.
5. I've entered BIOS and turned the Audio off and on again, rebooting in the meantime.
6. I've upgraded and updated Ubuntu (I suspect that might have broken the audio output and input in the first place).

Besides reinstalling Ubuntu, does anyone have ideas of how I could fix this? or what could be happening?

Since we are all in a global pandemic, it's absolutely affecting my job, personal tech projects, and some classes I give. It would be of great help. 
If you need any additional info about my system, I'd gladly give it.

I hope someone knows how to solve this ~fingers crossed~. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible help : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134282/ubuntu-18-04-sound-suddenly-stopped-working?rq=1 , https://askubuntu.com/questions/105765/ubuntu-11-10-sound-stopped-working-speakers-and-headphones?rq=1

Comment: thank you! I followed the steps in the first answer of the second link and it its all functioning again. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'd like to thank [AEM](https://askubuntu.com/users/1051814/aem) for pointing me to this link: [Sound Stopped Working (Speakers and Headphones)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105765/ubuntu-11-10-sound-stopped-working-speakers-and-headphones?rq=1)

I had tried everything and was desperate when I posted here.

In the end, just following the steps in This [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS) solved the problem.

In other words, just downloading and installing the `.deb` [Here](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+build/16817188).

Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome always my friend , Please don't forget to accept your answer , so others that have the similar problem can solve it too .Glad to help you!